# I want to save uploaded files in my local folder using angular2 or angular4

Tags: angular, angular-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload to upload files.when I upload file progress bar shows that file is uploaded but not save this file. now I want to save uploaded files in my local folder using angular2 or angular4.

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/tree/development/demo/src/app/components/file-upload .. see the `file-catcher.js` file example.

Comment: can you please explain how to use catcher file code with file-uploading.ts I already created file uploading from ng2-file-upload butt I don't know how to use file-catcher.js. I am a beginner in angular.thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: I cannot, I provided you with a working example, you should be able to figure out rest of the stuff.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with angular. Files are uploaded to your backend, and your backend does whatever it wants to do with them. Your backend could use NodeJS, Java, PHP, Perl, Python or whatever, but not angular.

Comment: Ok, thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

you must deploy Api service for save file in db or file System.  or you can deploy server layout by nodejs if you like Javascript.